# How to fallback to default language when listing nodes in a view if no translation is available

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

I have a list of projects, mostly in english, but some are translated in French.

When i visit the French version of my website, how can I list all projects that are translated in French and if no translation is available for a specific node, display the english counterpart.

Is that something possible in the view UI ? Or I'm guessing with a hook_query_alter.

Thanks,

Comment: I have a similar problem. I want to fallback to default language when no translation is available in the session language. I don't want to hide links or anything, just switch language to default when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [Alternative Language Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/alternative_language). There a lot of sub modules, but the base one will give you the functionality you are looking for.

> Allows a language to specify an alternative language. If a node
>   translation for a specific language does not exist, Drupal will try to
>   load the translation for the alternative language before throwing a
>   404.
>
> This module is useful if you have multiple languages and only one
>   language is typically translated. Rather than create all of the other
>   translations and maintain those, the non-translated languages can load
>   the node from the alternative language.
>
> For example, you have the following language configuration:
>
> - / - US English - default
> - /en-ca - Canada English - alternative language is US English
> - /fr-ca - Canada French
>
> There is a node /contact, you will get three URL's:
>
> - /contact - US English
> - /en-ca/contact - Canada English
> - /fr-ca/nous-joindre - Canada French
>
> There are only two versions of the
>   node, US English and CA French. The CA English uses it's alternative
>   language and loads the US English version so all three pages work and
>   the URL's are correct.